# How to set a single title for facetted xarray plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, python-xarray

I need to set a title for multiple plots each of which is drawn with Basemap.

The souce data is an xarray's DataArray object. The code uses DataArray.plot() to draw multiple plots on a single figure.

```
p = da_monthly_slice.plot(levels=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], cmap=plt.cm.Reds, x='longitude', y='latitude', col='time', col_wrap=3)

for i, ax in enumerate(p.axes.flatten()):
    ax.set_title('Month: %d' % i)
    ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
    ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')
    map = Basemap(llcrnrlat=-39.2,urcrnrlat=-33.9,llcrnrlon=140.8,urcrnrlon=150.0,resolution='i',ax=ax)
    map.readshapefile(shapefile1, 'CFA_DISTRICT_BODY', linewidth=0.5)

fig = plt.figure()
st = fig.suptitle("Number of days for each month meeting the criteria in 2017", fontsize="large")

plt.show()
```

This caused two figures drawn separately. One is for the multiple plots while the other one contains the title only.

How to make the title to show on the top of the multiple plots on the same figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fig = plt.figure()` creates a new figure. Remove that line.

You can use `plt.suptitle(..)` to create a title in the current figure.
Or you get the figure from the `FacetGrid`, it should be `p.fig`.